# Remove vertical space around align

Tags: spacing, align

I need to display math in my report, but is it possible to remove the vertical space around align*?

A little example is the following (where I just want the `align*` to have the same vertical space as a `\\`

```
\documentclass[10pt,danish,a4paper,oneside,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
\begin{align*}
  A{\cap}B\ & =\ {\left\{{b,d,e}\right\}}{\;}{\cap}{\;}{\left\{{a,b,f,g}\right\}}   \\
  \nonumber\ & =\ {\left\{{b}\right\}}
\end{align*}
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss \\
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, show a minimal example of what you find wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't, it makes the math harder to read

Comment: The math is taking to much space in my report as I have a page limit

Comment: To remove the space you may use the *minipage* environment. Use \begin{minipage}[t][*height of text*][t]{*yourtextsize*} and you will contain the height of the align environment.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,danish,a4paper,oneside,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\lipsum*[2]  
\begin{align*}
  A\cap B & = \{b,d,e\} \cap \{a,b,f,g\} \\
          & = \{b\}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Note, however, that this is very poor typography. (`lipsum` is just to generate dummy text.)

The four parameters state how much vertical space is inserted between text and a math display. The "short" version is used for `equation`, when the last line of text is short.

You should also check the way you're inputting math. You're using too much redundant braces (that in some cases give very bad results). It's quite rare to use explicit spacing commands in math.

Here's the result of typesetting the test file

[image]

This is the principle. In case you use font size changing commands, you have to tell LaTeX that you want this zero spacing in all sizes by putting this in the preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
```

so that the example becomes

```
\documentclass[10pt,danish,a4paper,oneside,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]  
\begin{align*}
  A\cap B & = \{b,d,e\} \cap \{a,b,f,g\} \\
          & = \{b\}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but the setlength's did not do it :(

Comment: It does. You probably have other display environments, I'll update my answer

Comment: It stills give me the same result, no space removed

Comment: Works for me as well, but makes me wondering why it doesn't work when the \setlength commands are set in the preamble.

Comment: @Philipp The parameters' values are set by `\normalsize` and other size changing commands, which might account for the OP's problem.

Comment: @The87Boy Are you using some font changing command such as `\small`?

Comment: Oh, now I figured out, why it did not work thanks to Philipp. I put it in the preample-file ;)

Comment: Egreg's solution has unwanted spaces at the end of the lines. They have to be suppressed by putting % at the end. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 24):

Use an inline equation (which adds no vertical space), place the macro `\displaystyle` within it (so it looks like a normal equation), place `aligned` within it (for alignment), and enclose it within `{\centering ... \par}` (to center without adding unnecessary vertical space).

```
{\centering
  $ \displaystyle
    \begin{aligned} 
       A{\cap}B\ & =\ {\left\{{b,d,e}\right\}}{\;}{\cap}{\;}{\left\{{a,b,f,g}\right\}}   \\
       \nonumber\ & =\ {\left\{{b}\right\}} 
    \end{aligned}
  $ 
\par}%Necessary for centering to work
```

It's a bit ugly if you're doing it a lot, but in my case it was handy because I wanted to remove vertical space from one or two equations (so they'd fit within a table) but not affect any others.

Comment: There is a little typo in your code - \displaysyle instead of \displaystyle.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! It also allows using `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` for respectively left- and right- alignment.
I'm making it into a macro for reuse :-)

Comment: Based on this, you could make your own environment:
`\newenvironment{closealign}{\par\centering$\displaystyle\begin{aligned}}{\end{aligned}$\par}`

Answer (score 9):

Egreg's solution has unwanted spaces at the end of the lines. They have to be suppressed by putting `%` at the end.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
```

Comment: I've updated egreg's answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\vspace{-0.5cm}` locally above each `\begin{align*}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).