# Spacing between align and list environement

Tags: spacing, lists, align

How can I reduce the spacing between the align and the list environment?

```
\begin{align*}
       {_C}\vOm=( 0, 0, 0 )
\end{align*}             <=== THERE IS STILL SOME SPACING inbetween?
 \begin{question}
      \item  askjdhaskldhklasdh klashd klajsd lökjas ldökjaslökdj 
 \end{question}
```

I have following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\parindent0.0ex
\topskip0pt
\partopsep0.0ex

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

\newcounter{questioncounter}
\newenvironment{question}{
  \begin{list}
  {({\itshape\alph{questioncounter}})}
  {\usecounter{questioncounter}
  \topsep=0pt
\partopsep=0pt
\parsep0.5ex \itemsep0.5ex  \leftmargin5ex \labelwidth5ex}}
  {\end{list}}



\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

This is just a normal text bla bla bla 
This is just a normal text bla bla bla 
\begin{align*}
  A\cap B & = \{b,d,e\} \cap \{a,b,f,g\}
\end{align*}
\begin{question}
 \item asdasd
 \item lkasjd lkajsd lökjasd 
\end{question}
This is just a normal text bla bla bla 
This is just a normal text bla bla bla 
\begin{align*}
  A\cap B & = \{b,d,e\} \cap \{a,b,f,g\}
\end{align*}
\begin{question}
 \item asdasd
 \item lkasjd lkajsd lökjasd 
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post _complete_ small documents. The spacing between those environments is stretchy so depends on other items in the page,and the page size, neither of which you have shown Your setting of `\topsep` and `\partopsep` look distinctly odd, they allow the spacing to be negative so one item overlapping the previous.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `%` in the definion of your list-environment, if you write

```
\newenvironment{question}{%    <-- note end-of-line %
...
```

things look better.

See e.g. [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions)