# Remove vertical space around multline chemical equation in a table

Tags: spacing, amsmath, multline

Is there any way to remove the vertical spacing around a chemical equation placed in a `multline` environment in a table?

I tried setting the length of display skips as suggested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align) but it doesn't seem to work.

Just as information, the `\ce` command doesn't cause this behavior; it is seen with normal math equations as well.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% This doesn't work.
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{rp{27em}l}
        1  & \begin{multline*}\ce{This is a very long list of products ->\\[-0.5em] This is another very long list of reactants}\end{multline*} & Align top \\
        2  & \ce{Na+ + Cl- -> NaCl} & Example \\
        3 & \begin{multline}
            This is not a chemical equation environment \\
            But theres still vertical spacing.
        \end{multline} & Align top
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: The last ‘equation’ has to be numbered?

Comment: `multline` is intended to form a new standalone display.  Instead, try `multlined`, which is a "subsidiary" structure.  This requires the `mathtools` package.

Comment: @Bernard No, it's just demonstrating that this occurs without the `\ce` command. However, I intend to use the `\ce` command in my actual text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `multlined` removes the vertical spacing, but the second line doesn't seem to be aligned right, it merely seems to be indented from the left. Is there any way to make the second line align right?

Comment: @ruby -- All the "subsidiary" multi-line environments just take up the horizontal space needed for the input expression.  If you want the last line of `multlined` to be farther to the right, you can/should add some additional `\hspace` at the beginning of that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `multlined` environments can take two optional arguments: its vertical position (`t, c` or `b`) and its width. I naturally chose the column width:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}

\setlength{\multlinegap}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{r|p{27em}|l}
        1 & $ \begin{multlined}[t][27em]\ce{This is a very long list of products ->\\This is another very long list of reactants}\end{multlined} $ & Align top \\
        2 & \ce{Na+ + Cl- -> NaCl} & Example \\
        3 &\leavevmode$ \begin{multlined}[t][27em]
            \text{This is not a chemical equation environment} \\
            \text{But theres still vertical spacing}.
        \end{multlined} $ & Align top
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure why (and can't test), but the two lines of item 1 are too close together.  Perhaps it's the effect of `\ce`, because item 3, where both lines are defined with `\text`, has almost too much space.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You're right – thank you for warning me! Examining the code, I found out  I hadn't noticed a useless  `\\[-0.5em]` in the code posted with the question. So it has nothing to do with the `\ce` command and I removed it. Thanks again.