# Different vertical spaces around equations of different height in the achemso document class

Tags: equations, vertical-spacing, achemso, vspace, belowdisplayskip

I would like to use documentclass `achemso` to format my Supplementary Material. However, this class puts different vertical spaces around equations of different height. In the following example:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{5pt}

\noindent Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
%
\begin{equation}
s=\sum\limits_{i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{3}M_j}^{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{3}m_k}a_i,    
\end{equation}
%
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
%
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2    
\end{equation}
%
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

there is much larger vertical space around Eq. (2) than around Eq. (1). Is there any way that this package does not vary the vertical spaces around the equations depending on the equation height?

Answer (score 1):

The standard settings apply `\doublespacing` from the `setspace` package, as the intention is to be manuscript-like. You can turn that off using

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{\singlespacing}
```

which should give you the same appearance as the `article` class.

Comment: Thank you. However, when I use `\onehalfspacing` the problem still stands.

Comment: @TobiR I think you are likely trying to achieve something the `achemso` class was never intended for. The set up is quite deliberately manuscript-like, as the primary target is paper submission. Supplementary data doesn't need to use the class at all: it's more that's it's convenient for people also using the class for their main text. If you want publication-like typesetting, I'd probably just use `article` and load such features as you need.

Answer (score 0):

`achesmo` loads `setspace` which by default scales up the display skips, you can prevent this by using

```
\RequirePackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
```

There is still some difference due to the built in TeX handling of tall and deep lines.

- The second equation gets the intended spacing, with the added space below being
  `\belowdisplayskip` + `\baselineskip` - depth of equation - height of the text `Blah...`
  (5pt -3pt + 23.99748pt - 8.33331pt =17.66417pt)
- The first equation is very deep so `\baselineskip` is not used so you get
  `\belowdisplayskip` +  `\lineskip`
  (5pt+1pt=6pt)

---

It is easier to see what is happening if (like TeX) you are not distracted by the structure of the subscript which in this unusual case has an obvious "baseline" of its own and takes up a large proportion of the total width of the expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\newcommand\test[1]{
\parbox[t]{1cm}{%
#1:xxx
\[
x_{\rule{1pt}{#1pt}}
\]
yyyy}}


\test{0}
\test{5}
\test{10}
\test{15}
\test{20}
\test{25}
\test{30}


\end{document}
```

TeX here is maintaining the baseline spacing of the equation to the following text that is from the baseline of the math *x* to the baseline of yyy, but once the depth of the expression is too great, baseline spacing is abandoned and to avoid over-printing the yyy text is moved down just enough to give `\lineskip` clearance.

Comment: Thanks David. You mention that the resulting space depends on the depth of the equation. Is there any way to turn off this unwanted feature?

Comment: @TobiR if you turn off the feature then the deep equation will over-print the following text. Once the depth of a line gets to be more than baselineskip tex does the emergency measure of dropping baselineskip spacing and just ensuring `\lineskip` space to stop the lines touching

Comment: @TobiR add `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` to the preamble,

Comment: Yes, this is terrible. I do not understand why Tex cannot format the equations uniformly. There is no reason to take these emergency actions.

Comment: So do I need to forget about having reasonable vertical spacing around equations?

Comment: @TobiR it does, it's just that you don't like the result. Note this behaviour isn't really related to display math it is endemic in tex linebreaking you see the same if you use `\includegraphics` mid-paragraph, or just do `\rule{1pt}{2cm}` mid paragraph, anything in the paragraph that means that you can not maintain even baseline spacing.

Comment: Not at all, you just need to re-assess (or define) reasonableness.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I need to act as fox in the Phaedrus tale: just redefine my need. ;)

Comment: @TobiR the point is that tex is trying to ignore the subscript so that  the space after `\[x_1\]` is the "same" as the space after `\[x\]`  (measured from the baseline of x.) however if you literally do that you get the overprinting so the following text is moved down just enough to give `\lineskip` clearance.

Comment: @TobiR But you are not TeX and see the structure of the subscript and have an inclination to base the following space not on the baseline of the equation as a whole but of the subscript, but tex simply does not have that information available, an `equation` is a single `hbox` and has height and depth and all it knows is that this equation has too much depth to fit in baseline spacing.

Comment: Hmmm... So TeX know nothing about the structure of the subscripts/superscripts. Thus, $X_{{{{{{{{1_{{1_1}_1}}_1}_1}_1}_1}_1}_1}_1}$ starts filling the vertical space reserved for $X$...

Comment: @TobiR I added an example to show this more clearly.  Obviously TeX knows the structure of the subscript while laying out the subscript, but no longer when it is adding the equation to the page, by then the equation is just an box, so just the three numbers height, depth, width.

Comment: Yeah, but it is not clear why TeX does not measure the vertical space from the deepest/tallest object of the equation (that is, the deepest "_1" in my example).

Comment: @TobiR because it is intentionally _not_ doing that to preserve baseline spacing. that is it is optimised so the first three yyy are at the same position, and are not affected by the depth of the subscript. You could say that is not the best algorithm possible but it is what Knuth implemented, the box and glue model is very powerful but its simplicity does have some costs here in loss of knowledge of internal structure. But if you change the box and glue model you are using a new typesetter not TeX.

Comment: Really thanks David. It helped a lot.